# Rounded corner in xy package and ellipse shape

Tags: xy-pic, shapes, bugs, xymatrix

This question very hard for me. `xy` package have also the shapes, circle with `[o]`, or other forms using this table:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[all]{xy}
    \begin{document}
    \xymatrix{
*++++[F-:<5pt>]{\txt{High\\label}}\ar[dr] & &\\
& *++++[F-:<5pt>]{\txt{Second text}}\ar[r] & 
}
    \end{document}
```

I have tried a code but....to increase the long text into the shape I must to add severals `+`. My output is:

[image]

where I see in the rounded corner (see the red square) a strange closure. Is it normal? But if I would to have an ellipse, is it possible with `xy` package, option `\xymatrix`?

Comment: I get correct joins when I use `pdflatex`

Comment: @egreg I was using `XeLaTeX` with Papeeria. :-).....one question is solved. And for the ellipse? (Often I done many edits because before I must to think in Italian). :-(